# How to render view in react google map marker?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-google-maps

I need to draw the circle inside my marker and change their circle color dynamically, do we have any options to render view in react google map icon.

My marker looks similar to the below link picture and i need to draw the circle inside the marker png image and change their color dynamically. Any help will be highly appreciated.

[1] : https://cdn4.vectorstock.com/i/1000x1000/29/18/map-marker-flat-yellow-color-icon-vector-6082918.jpg

Here is my piece of code

```
<Marker
      position={{ lat: shop.location.latitude, lng: shop.location.longitude }}

      icon={{
        url: "/design/images/car-g.png",
        scale: scale || 0.5,
        strokeWeight: 0.2,
        strokeColor: "black",
        strokeOpacity: 1,
        fillColor: shop.mapIconColor,
        fillOpacity: 1,
        labelOrigin: new window.google.maps.Point(16, 10)
      }}
      onClick={onClick}
      zIndex={zIndex}

    >
      <InfoBox
        options={{
          closeBoxURL: ``,
          enableEventPropagation: true,
          alignBottom: true,
          pixelOffset: new window.google.maps.Size(-16, -50 * scale),
          disableAutoPan: true
        }}
      >
        <div
          style={{

          }}
        >

        </div>
      </InfoBox>
    </Marker>
```

Comment: You can create multiple marker png with different colored circles then you can use those marker icon png as your icon. That way, you can put conditions when to use the marker with specific color as your marker icon.